# Redirecting page from Thymeleaf template

Tags: thymeleaf

How to redirect the page from Thymeleaf (I have JSP code like below)

```
out.println("REDIRECT=http://www.example.com/api/response?id="+id)
```

What is the equivalent in Thymeleaf? I want to do it from the template.

Comment: what exactly you are trying to achieve, could you explain the flow

Answer (score 6):

Thymeleaf doesn't provide any mechanism for redirecting to another page from one of its templates -- and I wouldn't recommend doing it anyways (since this is something that should probably be handled at the controller level).

That being said, it's possible to do this using javascript.  Something like this:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/api/response?id=' + [[${id}]];
</script>
```

Or possibly the meta refresh tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" th:attr="content=${'5; url=http://example.com/api/response?id=' + id}" />
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.